# Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>`

Tags: typescript, express, passport.js

I have the below function in an express typescript project that uses passportjs:

```
import passport from 'passport';
import { Router } from 'express';

const router = Router();

router.get('/login', oauth.authenticate('oauth2'));

router.get(
  '/oauth2/callback',
  oauth?.authenticate('oauth2'),
  (req: UserRequest, res: Response) => {
    if (req.user && req.user.code) {
      const destination =
        req.session.source_url || process.env.front_end_url || '/';
      req.session.source_url = undefined;
      return res.redirect(`${process.env.base_url}/complete-auth?destination=${destination}`);

    } else {
      return res.status(401).json({
        authenticated: false,
        message: 'User has failed authentication'
      });
    }
  }
);
```

The UserRequest type looks like this:

```
import { Request } from 'express';
import { Session } from 'express-session';


declare module "express-session" {
  interface Session {
    source_url: string;
  }
}

export interface UserRequest extends Request {
 user: {
   code: string;
   refresh: string;
   sub: string;
   given_name: string;
   family_name: string;
   email: string
   exp: number;
 }
 session: Session;
}
```

However when I run the linter I get this error

```
Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `RequestHandler<{}, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>`                @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
 
Unsafe argument of type `any` assigned to a parameter of type `RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>`  @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
```

I'm not sure how to resolve this tbh, grateful for any help

Comment: I am unsure how you solved the problem, but I usually either adding a rule ignore, or enforcing types with `: <Type>` or `as <Type>`.

Comment: Is `oauth` global here? And which lines does the linter mark as rule violations?